# Having trouble implementing Minimax algorithm into my JavaScript Tic-Tac-Toe game

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I have my game set up so the computer makes the first move. It seems every game should end in a draw, but the computer picks the next available spot.

JS:

```
   const GameBoard = (() => {
    const winConditions = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6]
    ];
    let slots = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    const player1 = "X";
    const player2 = "O";
    let currentPlayer = player2;
    const playerText = document.querySelector(".player");
    const computerText = document.querySelector(".computer");
    const winnerText = document.querySelector(".winner-text");
    let isRunning = false;
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  
  
    function initializeGame() {
      computerText.classList.add("highlighted");
      isRunning = true;
      ComputerPlayer.bestMove(); 
  
      cells.forEach((cell) => {
        cell.addEventListener("click", function () {
          cellClicked(cell);
        });
  
        const restartBtn = document.querySelector("#restart-btn");
        restartBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
          restartGame(cell);
          initializeGame(); 
          
        });
      });
     
    }
    function cellClicked(item) {
      const cellIndex = item.getAttribute("cell-index");
      console.log(cellIndex);
      console.log(item);
      if (currentPlayer === player1) {
        if (slots[cellIndex] != "" || !isRunning) {
          return;
        }
        updateCell(item, cellIndex);
        checkForWinner();
        checkGameOver();
        switchPlayers();

      }
    }
    function updateCell(cell, index) {
      slots[index] = currentPlayer;
      console.log(slots);
      cell.textContent = currentPlayer;
    }
  
    function switchPlayers() {
      if (isRunning) {
        if (currentPlayer === player1) {
          currentPlayer = player2;
          console.log(`current player is: ${currentPlayer}`);
          playerText.classList.remove("highlighted");
          computerText.classList.add("highlighted");
          ComputerPlayer.bestMove(); 
          console.log(`current player is: ${currentPlayer}`);
        } else if (currentPlayer === player2) {
          currentPlayer = player1;
          console.log(`current player is: ${currentPlayer}`);
          computerText.classList.remove("highlighted");
          playerText.classList.add("highlighted");
        }
      }
    }
    function equals3(a,b,c) {
        if (a == b && b == c) {
            return true; 
        }
        return false; 
    }
  
    function checkForWinner() { 
        let winner = null; 
        for(let i = 0; i < winConditions.length; i++) {
            if (equals3(slots[winConditions[i][0]],slots[winConditions[i][1]],slots[winConditions[i][2]]) == true && slots[winConditions[i][0]] != '') {
                winner = slots[winConditions[i][0]]; 
            }
            if ((winner === null) && (slots[0] != '' && slots[1] != '' && slots[2] != '' && slots[3] != '' && slots[4] != '' && slots[5] != '' && slots[6] != '' && slots[7] != '' && slots[8] != '')) {
                return 'Tie'; 
            } else {
                return winner; 
            }
        }
    }
    function checkGameOver() {
        let result = checkForWinner(); 
        if (result != null) {
            isRunning = false; 
            winnerText.classList.add('winner-visible'); 
            winnerText.textContent = result + ' Wins!'; 
        } else {
            isRunning = true; 
        }
    }
  

    function restartGame(card) {
      isRunning = true;
      slots = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
      console.log(slots);
      card.textContent = "";
      winnerText.classList.remove("winner-visible");
    }
    
    
    return {
      winConditions,
      slots,
      player1,
      player2,
      currentPlayer,
      playerText,
      computerText,
      winnerText,
      cells,
      isRunning,
      switchPlayers,
      updateCell,
      checkForWinner, 
      initializeGame
     
    };
  })();
  const ComputerPlayer = (() => {
    
        function bestMove() {
            if (GameBoard.currentPlayer === GameBoard.player2) {
            let bestScore = -Infinity; 
            let move; 
            for(let i = 0 ; i < GameBoard.slots.length; i++) {
                if (GameBoard.slots[i] === '') {
                    GameBoard.slots[i] = 'O'; 
                    let score = minimax(GameBoard.slots,0, true); 
                    GameBoard.slots[i] = ''; 
                    if (score > bestScore) {
                        bestScore = score; 
                        move = i; 
                    }
                }
          
             }
           
             GameBoard.slots[move] = 'O'; 
             console.log(GameBoard.slots)
             GameBoard.cells[move].textContent = 'O'; 
             GameBoard.switchPlayers(); 
            }
            
        }
        let scores = {
            X: 1,
            O: -1, 
            Tie: 0
        }


        function minimax(board, depth, isMaximizing) {
            let result = GameBoard.checkForWinner(); 
            if (result !== null) {
                return scores[result]; 
            }
            if (isMaximizing) {
                let bestScore = -Infinity; 
                for(let i = 0 ; i < board.length; i++) {
                    if(board[i] === '') {
                        board[i] = 'O'; 
                        let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, false); 
                        board[i] = ''; 
                       bestScore = Math.max(score, bestScore); 

                    }
                }
                return bestScore;   
            } else {
                let bestScore = Infinity; 
                for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++ ) {
                    if(board[i] === '') {
                        board[i] = 'X'; 
                        let score = minimax(board, depth+1, true); 
                        board[i] = ''; 
                        bestScore = Math.min(score, bestScore);
                    }
                }
                return bestScore; 
            }

        }

        return {
            bestMove, 
            scores, 
            minimax
        }
    


        
  })();
GameBoard.initializeGame();
```

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    

          <div class="player-section">
            <div class="player">Player</div>
          </div>
        
           
            <div class="game">
             <div class="game-contents">
                    <div class="card" id="one" cell-index='0'>
                    <div class="card-text"></div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="card" id="two" cell-index='1'>
                    <div class="card-text"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" id="three" cell-index='2'>
                    <div class="card-text"></div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="card" id="four" cell-index='3'>
                    <div class="card-text"></div>
                     </div>
                    <div class="card" id="five" cell-index='4'>
                    <div class="card-text"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" id="six" cell-index= '5'>
                    <div class="card-text"></div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="card" id="seven" cell-index='6'>
                    <div class="card-text"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" id="eight" cell-index='7'>
                    <div class="card-text"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" id="nine" cell-index='8'>
                    <div class="card-text"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="winner-content">
                    <div class="winner-text"></div>
                    <button id="restart-btn">Restart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
           
     
        <div class="computer-section">
            <div class="computer">Computer</div>
        </div> 
    
       
</div>
       
        
            

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600&family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: 500;
    gap:20%; 
}


.game {
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
   

   
}
.game-contents {
    background-color: black;
    display: grid;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    
}

.card {
    width: 1fr;
    height: 1fr; 
    border: .5px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    transition: box-shadow .3s;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 0
}
.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 11px rgba(255, 255, 255);
}
#one {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

#two {
     grid-column: 2 / 3;
     grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

#three {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
}


#four {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

#five {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

#six {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

#seven {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
}

#eight {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 3/ 4;
}

#nine {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
}
.player {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.computer {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.highlighted {
    color: yellow; 
}
.winner-content {
    color: white;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    width: 200px;
    font-weight: 700;
    gap: 10px;
}
.winner-text {
    visibility: hidden; 
}
.winner-visible {
    visibility: visible; 

}
#restart-btn {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

I tried rewriting my checkForWinner function but there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it. I know my checkGameOver function isn't working properly but its only use is for displaying the winner on the screen.

Comment: So you'll have to debug your program.

Comment: Does it keep picking the next best spot or just as first move? Since Tic Tac Toe is a draw you won't find a better move than the first available spot as first move.